# Triggering CSS transition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition, fadein

I want to trigger a CSS transition (fade-in message) in Javascript (using no framework) when there is an error. I added a trigger class to my div, but it doesn't fade in when the error pops up. Any ideas how I could fix this?

HTML file:

```
<div id="errorID" class="errorMessage">
    <strong>Error!</strong> Something went wrong.
</div>
```

Javascript file:

```
if (!valid){ // error -> errorTextMessage
    var errorBox = document.getElementsById('errorID');
    errorBox.classList.add("errorTrigger");
}
```

CSS file:

```
.errorMessage{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }

.errorMessage.errorTrigger{
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: there is a typo `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: @Bhuwan Thank you man you saved my life! Didn't see that typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bhuwan said, I had a typo at `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-transition` is an **experimental** property that webkit-based browsers used (a long time ago) when testing their implementations of `transition`.

It should never be used in production and no modern browser supports it.

Use the real `transition` property.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm gonna use that from now on.